# Spring security taglib and custom namespace filter

Tags: security, taglib, intercept, authorize

I'm using Spring 3.1.0 and I'm encountering a behavior I would classify as a bug. Yet I believe there's a bigger chance it's my fault. Any help is very appreciated.

I've successfully followed the advices for [creating <intercept-url pattern> dynamically with spring security 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6875220/creating-intercept-url-pattern-dynamically-with-spring-security-3). So I've successfully configured a http namespace to use a securityMetadataSource of my own.

Notice that I'm aware it's not recommended. But the fact I'm not having it working as expected makes me feel that I'm missing something important.

As described in the [linked thread above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6875220/creating-intercept-url-pattern-dynamically-with-spring-security-3) I've managed to have a configuration like the following working properly:

```
<http>
  <form-login login-page="/login" 
    default-target-url="/welcome"
    always-use-default-target="false" 
    authentication-failure-url="/login?error=1" 
    />
  <logout logout-url="/logout.secure" logout-success-url="/" />
  <http-basic/>
  <custom-filter ref="myFilterSecurityInterceptor"
    before="FILTER_SECURITY_INTERCEPTOR" />
</http>
```

So, myFilterSecurityInterceptor uses mySecurityMetadataSource where I define SecurityConfig instances like "ROLE_ADMIN", "IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY", etc.; and AntPathRequestMatcher instances to check. And it works: if the user has not a given role, access is denied to the paths where it's required.

The problems are with security taglib.

According to Spring documentation on security taglibs ([here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/reference/taglibs.html)), to use `<security:authorize>` tag

> there must also be an instance of WebInvocationPrivilegeEvaluator in your application context. If you are using the namespace, one will automatically be registered.

At the first call of `<security:authorize url="" >...</security:authorize>` an exception is thrown as it appears that no `WebSecurityExpressionHandler` implementing bean is found. In effects, my  `myFilterSecurityInterceptor` uses `mySecurityMetadataSource` that implements `FilterInvocationSecurityMetadataSource`. So my filter implementation does not handle expressions. And nowhere in my configuration I declare such a bean. Effectively I thought no expression handling would have been required, as I didn't asked any in my `<http>` declaration and as the documentation above says:

> The first approach uses a web-security expression, specified in the access attribute of the tag. The expression evaluation will be delegated to the SecurityExpressionHandler defined in the application context (you should have web expressions enabled in your  namespace configuration to make sure this service is available). [...]
>   This tag can also operate in an alternative mode which allows you to define a particular URL as an attribute.

So I believed that no expression handling should be required as I've used the second approach of using `<security:authorize>`: **url** method and not **access** method.

Anyway, I can avoid the exception above adding the following attribute to the `<http>` declaration:

```
use-expressions="true"
```

Having done this latter refinement to my configuration I obtain that:
1) my role-based authorization (implemented in `mySecurityMetadataSource` and checking url matching against simple strings as "ROLE_ADMIN" or "IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY") works properly, denying the access to an url if the user has not got the required authorization;
2) the `<security:authorize>` tags find no interceptor declared (the custom filter setting in the `<http>` seems ignored) so every link is shown, no matter which roles the user sports.

So my question is: is it (easily) possible to mix `<security:authorize>` tag with a SecurityMetadataSource of your own?

Thank you in advance for any help or hint.
Ciao
Alessandro